# If string contains any element of vector

Tags: regex, string, r, extract

I have such a problem:
I have 2 txt-files. 
One looks like this:

```
ABCG1
ABLIM1
ABP1
ACOT11
ACP5
```

And contains 700+ strings, and the second one looks like this:

```
1       2       3       4       5       6       GENE_NAME
0.01857 0.02975 0.02206 0.01847 0.01684 0.01588 NIPA2;NIPA2;NIPA2;NIPA2
0.81992 0.8168  0.76963 0.83116 0.78114 0.85544 MAN1B1
0.13053 0.12308 0.10654 0.11675 0.13664 0.10312 TSEN34;TSEN34
0.91888 0.93095 0.91498 0.91558 0.91126 0.91569 LRRC16A
```

and it's dimension is 90+x640 000+

I want to extract strings of 2nd tab-delimited file, that contains any values of first one. I thought of something like that:

```
data=x[1,]
data=data[-1,]
for (i in 1:nrow(test)){
    if (grepl("gene_name",test[i,]$GENE_NAME=="TRUE")){
    data_temp=x[i,]
    data=rbind(data,data_temp)
    rm(data_temp)
    }
```

But the problem I have to repeat this code for 700+ times. Is there any way to write smth like this:

```
value= c(vector that contains my gene names)
string= (one of srings of my table)
grepl(any(value),string)
```

I met the problem with `any` because it makes vector logical instead of character. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you add "GENE_NAME" as a column header in the first file you could do: `merge(df1,df2,by="GENE_NAME")`. Where df1 and df2 are the files as data frames

Answer (score 0):

Would that work for you?

```
value <- c("ABCG1",
          "ABLIM1",
          "ABP1",
          "ACOT11",
          "ACP5")


GENE_NAME <- c("ABCG1;NIPA2;NIPA2",
           "ABLIM1",
           "ABP1;ABCG1",
           "ACOT11",
           "TSEN34;TSEN34",
           "ACP5",
           "LRRC16A") # This is the test$GENE_NAME column

lapply(value, function(x) GENE_NAME[grepl(x, GENE_NAME)])
# [[1]]
# [1] "ABCG1;NIPA2;NIPA2" "ABP1;ABCG1"       
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "ABLIM1"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "ABP1;ABCG1"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "ACOT11"
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] "ACP5"
```

You can unlist it if you like

```
unlist(lapply(value, function(x) GENE_NAME[grepl(x, GENE_NAME)]))
# [1] "ABCG1;NIPA2;NIPA2" "ABP1;ABCG1"        "ABLIM1"            "ABP1;ABCG1"        "ACOT11"           
# [6] "ACP5"
```